# Split C# code into 2 methods to be more SOLID

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, solid-principles

Im trying to rewrite my current piece of code into (see example0. But it doesnt know the carriage animal in my CheckIfAnimalFits method. How would I fix this without moving the entire foreach into the method

Current code

```
public bool AddAnimaltoWagon(Animal animal)
{
    if (CheckWagonFull(animal) == true ) { return false; }

    foreach (Animal carriageAnimal in Animals)
    {
        if (carriageAnimal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore 
          && animal.Size <= carriageAnimal.Size 
          || animal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore 
          && animal.Size > carriageAnimal.Size)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Animals.Add(animal);
    return true;
}
```

trying to get

```
public bool AddAnimaltoWagon(Animal animal)
{
    if (CheckWagonFull(animal) == true ) { return false; }

    foreach (Animal carriageAnimal in Animals)
    {
        if (CheckIfAnimalFits == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Animals.Add(animal);
    return true;
}

public bool CheckIfAnimalFits(Animal animal)
{
    if (carriageAnimal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore 
       && animal.Size <= carriageAnimal.Size 
       || animal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore 
       && animal.Size > carriageAnimal.Size)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So it doesnt know `carriageAnimal` in my new method

Comment: You must be getting compilation error. Also pass `carriageAnimal` to method `CheckIfAnimalFits` function. i.e. `CheckIfAnimalFits (animal, carriageAnimal)` and defined method as `CheckIfAnimalFits(Animal animal, Animal carriageAnimal)`

Comment: @Satpal thanks indeed it was as easy as passing both. And no im not having any compilation errrors why?

Comment: `if (CheckIfAnimalFits == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }` should be `return CheckIfAnimalFits(carriageAnimal);`

Comment: `Animal  : Animals`  please show the relationship, you are mixing names which should not be possiable, so show all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say your new method doesn't know carriageAnimal, you should look where that variable originally comes from: it's the foreach variable. Thus you have to pass it to your new function as well. Try this:

```
public bool AddAnimaltoWagon(Animal animal)
{
    if (CheckWagonFull(animal) == true ) { return false; }

    foreach (Animal carriageAnimal in Animals)
    {
        if (CheckIfAnimalFits(carriageAnimal, animal) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Animals.Add(animal);
    return true;
}

public bool CheckIfAnimalFits(Animal carriageAnimal, Animal animal)
{
    if (carriageAnimal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore && animal.Size <= carriageAnimal.Size || animal.AnimalDiet == AnimalDiet.Carnivore && animal.Size > carriageAnimal.Size)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```